# Options for getting a CPU intensive job off my web server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, amazon-dynamodb

I have been working on a Web App for visualizing live data. It is crucial that this data is kept up to date on the client side without such updates being invoked directly by the client (e.g. no button presses or refreshing the page). Currently, on page load, I grab the current data set from a database (DynamoDB) via Ajax, and subsequent updates are pushed to any listening clients every 5 minutes via a Websockets connection (using Socket.io).

I have overlooked the computational load of this update job. It has to mine some data, process it, update the database, and send the update out to all clients. As a result, the web server is left unresponsive for about 30 seconds with each update. Furthermore, my current architecture limits me from putting my server behind a load balancer, which is something I anticipate coming up in the future. For both these reasons, I really need to get this update job off my web server.

I am relatively inexperienced in web development, and I don't feel I am knowledgeable enough about these technologies to know the drawbacks of the solutions I have come up with. Currently, I am considering:

1. Break the update off into a separate process so it does not block the Node event loop. This would solve my issue in the short term, but if I ever want to load balance my application, I can't have the update running on multiple machines.
2. Drop Websockets entirely and just have the client query the database every 5 minutes, while a separate process (or separate server if I want load balancing) keeps the database up to date without interacting directly with the client. Will this kind of access pattern put too much load on my db?
3. Have a separate server run the update, and send the result via Websockets (or maybe some other protocol) to my load balanced application servers, which then push that update to all listening clients as usual. Is this even possible?

Perhaps there are other solutions. It seems like this would be a relatively common problem, so I was hoping I could find some guidance here. What are the potential issues with the solutions I have proposed, and are there other possible solutions that my suit my use case better?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want one process sitting somewhere which crunches the data and publishes it to a stream. Clients can then subscribe to the stream as and when they like. Redis handles streams nicely, you could process your data and push it into a redis stream. You could then create a small node service which subscribes to the redis stream and pushes the formatted data out over a websocket or via polling.

In this scenario you can then scale up either the publishing process (the one crunching the numbers) if your data load goes up, or scale up your subscribed process (which serves the data over a websocket to browsers) if you get an influx of clients watching the data.

You can also easily distribute the hosting of these services across other machines, and even write them in different languages if you decide the number crunching needs something like threading.

You're then left with the issue of clients (web browsers) consuming this data with a load balance in-between. This can be a hard problem if you use websockets and is bundled with pros and cons. But importantly you'll have separated your data crunching from your result publishing and that'll isolate out your issue to only the load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

I have done pretty much the same to check ressources on some of our servers.
I have a C# service getting the information on each server that we manage, sending them to a queue (Amq).

From there, I have a stomp client fetching data from amq and emiting them to a websocket.

My main micro service is fetching the data to save them into a db.

My visualisation webapp is connected to the same ws and is fetching the data as they are sent to display them.

The Amq step isn't mandatory at all, it's just something I had to work with (historical).

I don't know what type of data your are working with, so I don't know if my solution can apply to you.
Don't hesitate if I'm not clear or you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big question and I'm not going to try and give you a definitive answer.

**For option 2**

It really depends on how expensive your queries are. You can make DynamoDB fast if you pay for enough throughput. That said, on the face it, re-loading your whole dataset, when that sounds like its probably large, probably isn't good engineering.

**For option 3**

This option seems best to me if its achievable, although admittedly its hard to say with such a complex system - obviously you can't share your whole project.

Given your are already using AWS you might want to look into [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). If you can move the update process into a stand alone job, you can host it on lambda and move the load off the web server. Lambda is essentially infinitely scalable and you only pay for the compute you use.

This really depends on you being able to split the update task off into a separate service. Its likely you would need a fair bit of refactoring to isolate it as a service. If you can break little bits off at a time, and make the move gradually, even better.

If you consider trying this, and you've not used Lambda before, I would definitely start small with some hello world examples. Then try a very simple service in your application, and build up to taking on the update service.

You might also consider looking in [AWS Simple Message Queue Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) to handle the comms between clients and server.

**Database tuning**

If a lot of your update time is spent waiting for database actions to complete, rather than server processing, you can consider tuning that side of things up. Things to consider are:

- Buying more throughput
- Using batch operations (as these move load to DynamoDB from your server)
- Tuning keys, indexes and database access